# How to Make Column Name = DB Column in Talend

Tags: talend

Is there a way to make the column name = DB column name when this is the case:

- ------> tMap ------> tOracleOutput

I am facing an error the column name exists when creating the new destination table. the column name is written correctly; however, the db column name takes the old one. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the schema at the tOracleOutput component. As per my understanding you can edit the schema's DB column to reflect to a new column name.

Comment: I can edit it; however, my question is that I'd like Talend to get the same names as Column names automatically.

Comment: By default, if a new tOracleOutput component is created and connected to some input flow,  then the DB column at the tOracleOutput's built-in schema would be same as that of column name.  If you use a repository schema then you may have to manually change the DB column name in the repository schema.

Comment: I am using tOracleOutput's built-in schema, and the issue is when two columns Names ID and ID1 the DB Column name is ID for both columns